# raspberry pi b+ memory display as 247Mb

Tags: linux-kernel, raspberry-pi

I have raspberry pi b+ model.
I have seen in specifications, it says, it has 512mb ram.
but when i test it using free -m, it displays only 247mb.
Please tell me the reason for that.
Thank you.

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/Desktop/song $ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           247        210         36          0         15        103
-/+ buffers/cache:         91        155
Swap:           99          0         99
```

Comment: Likely you either don't have a kernel (or bootloader?) which considers 512Mb a possibility (perhaps your distro predates the B+?), your board doesn't actually have that, or some aspects of the hardware falsely indicates that it doesn't.

Comment: Thank you for quick response, 
Some times it will share with video. But do how i check?
sorry, i cant understand this "Likely you either don't have a kernel"

Comment: Shared video memory may make the difference between 256 and 247, but I doubt it covers the magnitude of difference you are seeing.  What I meant is that you might be running an old version of the software that might not know about the B+'s extra memory as a possibility.

Comment: I have updated the software.
where do i can check the shared memory size?
Thank you.

Comment: @mgms_kumara, can you tell what's in `/boot/config.txt` lines like gpu_mem or gpu_mem_512. But then again video ram could not account for that much. Please be also welcomed to http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ with RaspberryPi specific questions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your GPU memory down:

```
sudo raspi-config
```

you can select

```
8 Advanced Options                                   Configure advanced settings
```

then

```
A3 Memory Split            Change the amount of memory made available to the GPU
```

then you can set it to the expceted value.